# I can't set full HD resolution in my Lenovo

Tags: resolution, lenovo-laptop

I bought a Lenovo Z50-70 few days ago. I'm trying to set full HD resolution 1920x1080, but the maximum available is 1366x768. This laptop reportedly has a full HD screen. Graphic card drivers are the newest possible.

Comment: HD is 720p or higher. 1366x768 is 720p.

Comment: i want to set 1920x1080 but there is not such an option in control panel.

Comment: @PolishRandom What is the model number of your laptop?  It starts with 594.

Comment: You don't have a 1920x1080 screen apparently... that's why it won't let you set that resolution.

Comment: 1366×768 is definitely *not* 720p. 720p is 1,280×720, by definition. 1366×768 is, if anything, 768p.

Comment: @CodyGray But it is *higher* than the HD standard, which means it should be able to render HD video/images/whatever.

Comment: why is this question ever upvoted? No detailed hardware info. No OS info. No screenshot. Not replying to the only answer? What's wrong with you people?

Comment: What is Full HD for you? 1080p?

Answer (score 21):

You may have inadvertently purchased the HD model with a max resolution of 1366x768.

According to the specifications, the HD model has a resolution of 1366x768, and the FHD has a specification of 1920x1080.

> [Lenovo Z50 Technical Specification | Lenovo IL](http://shop.lenovo.com/il/en/tech-specs/laptops/lenovo-z50/)
>
> Some: 15.6" (396.2mm) **HD (1366x768)** color, LED backlight, 16:9 aspect ratio, 200 nits, 400:1 contrast ratio
>
> Some: 15.6" (396.2mm) **FHD (1920x1080)** color, LED backlight, 16:9 aspect ratio, 200 nits, 400:1 contrast ratio

Comment: _"This laptop reportedly has a full HD screen"_

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In my research, several sites only mention the full HD display.  The question initially apologized for bad English.  Perhaps, the user inadvertently purchased the wrong model or referenced specs from a different Z50-70 model (there are 19 models of Z50-70's listed on the Lenovo site).

Comment: @Steven oh boy, where are the days where a model name would identify the actual model rather than just the chassis stuff gets packed into.

Comment: @Steve: Yes, perhaps.